# Cannot get correct results from Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to query my database using Linq.  In short, my linq statement is not returning the data that I want and I am getting errors.

```
public class Product{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        public string Name{get;set;}
        [MinLength(10)]
        public string Description{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [Range(0, double.MaxValue)]
        public decimal Price{get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;

        public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories{get;set;}
    }

public class Category{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;

        public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories{get;set;}
    }

public class ProductCategory{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}
        public int ProductId{get;set;}
        public int CategoryId{get;set;}

        public Product Product{get;set;}
        public Category Category{get;set;}
    }

#Variable used in troublesome code (in controller)
Product product = context.Products
                .Include(p => p.ProductCategories)
                .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id);

#Troublesome code (in controller)
List<Category> categories = context.Categories
                .Include(c => c.ProductCategories)
                .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Product)
                .Where(c => c.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Product) != product)
                .ToList();
```

Products and Categories have a many to many relationship.  I want the categories variable to contain a list of all categories that are NOT in the retrieved product.  Cannot somebody guide me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Error:
'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used as the data type for a sequence with an ItemExpression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'

Comment: `List\`1` is the ToString() representation of `categories`. If that is what you see, the problem is in how you print it. Edit: I swear your title contained the text `List\`1`. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre], including all relevant code, desired output and actual errors.

Comment: `and I am getting errors`  It would be helpful if you told us what those errors are.

Comment: This line looks wrong: `.Where(c => c.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Product) != product)`

Comment: Seems like you'd want `.Where(c => !product.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Category).Contains(c))` to get the categories not associated with `product`.

Comment: @juharr, that worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, the direct error is in

```
c.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Product) != product
```

Because `c.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Product)` is a sequence of `Product`s, which can't be compared to one `Product`.

Another issue is that you use `product` in the second query. Even when used correctly, for example...

```cs
List<Category> categories = context.Categories
                .Include(c => c.ProductCategories)
                .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Product)
                .Where(c => !c.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Product)
                    .Any(p => p == product))
                .ToList();
```

...the problem is that `product` can't be translated into SQL and EF switches to client-side evaluation.

(I assume you're working in EF-core. EF6 wouldn't allow it and throw an exception if you'd use `product` like that in a subsequent query).

But there's a simple solution that even saves you one roundtrip. Just use `id` directly:

```cs
List<Category> categories = context.Categories
                .Include(c => c.ProductCategories)
                .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Product)
                .Where(c => !c.ProductCategories.Any(pc => pc.ProductId == id))
                .ToList();
```